# Moving to a second view controller from one view controller programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

1. I have added a second View Controller to my Main.storyboard. I have given it a title `lbvc`. My first view controller is named `JPViewController`
2. In my first view controller `JPViewController.m` file, I'd like to move to that view controller, in code, inside a specific method.

The code I have right now, but I think there are some problems, specifcally on the second line where I am not sure what to have in place of `SomethingHere`.

Thanks very much in advance guys!

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
SomethingHere *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"lbvc"];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `SomethingHere` with `UIViewController` and put `storyboardID` for your second vc as `lbvc` else your app will crash.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"lbvc"];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Whenever you are unsure what to use at `SomethingHere` always use `UIViewController`, because `UIViewController` is parent of all ViewControllers.

In some scenarios you want to pass some values to second vc, at that time you will need to use your actual class name which is assigned for second vc.

### Example

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
SecondVC *viewController = (SecondVC *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"lbvc"];
viewController.strABC = @"abc value";
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Hey Yogesh, thanks! Using the first example, I am still getting the app crashing. Perhaps I haven't created the View Controller in the storyboard properly? One thing I notice is that, whilst I have created the view controller on the storyboard, I don't have any .h or .m files in my project, relating to that view controller. Is that a problem?

Comment: @JP89 have you set the `storyboardID` for second vc? Nope, that's not a problem. The problem is you are not setting the  `storyboardID`.

Comment: `UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"lbvc"];`

Like that? Or do you mean I should replace `lbvc` with `storyboardId`?

Comment: In storyboard you need to put, not in code. Select your VC and click on Identity inspector, there is `storyboardId`.

Comment: @JP89 Go to `Identity inspector` not to `Attributes Inspector`.

Comment: Ah! Perfect, works. Thank you so much. I will continue with your second example so I can pass data. Quick question though, now that I have created the second view controller, how do you access the file so I can write code for that VC?

Comment: @JP89 Your quick question is too broad, Use this tutorial http://www.ralfebert.de/archive/ios/tutorial_iosdev/viewcontroller/

Answer (score 0):

you have to give the name of the second view controller in the place of something here, your creating a instance of the secondview controller there and pushing your control from first view to the second in the next line. hop it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using segues to navigate between view controller, use `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` on your view controller object to programmatically invoke the navigation to second view controller:

Answer (score 0):

First answer to you question, if you are instantiatingViewController by its storyboard id, it means that you are sure what type of object it will return. The `instantiateViewController` method always return `UIViewController` type. So you can cast it to your ViewController type.

```
SecondVC *secondVC = (SecondVC *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"lbvc"];
```

Secondly, Best way to use the storyboard object is to get the object from which the ViewController was loaded. [Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSViewController/storyboard)

```
//If creating it from AppDelegate Class
UIViewController *viewController = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"lbvc"];
//If you are creating it in some ViewController
UIViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"lbvc"];
```

[image]

The reason of using it as suggested is because if you will try to get object using the code below, it will create a new object of storyboard and then return. [Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIStoryboard/storyboardWithName:bundle:)

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
```

[image]